# Button Click: open a new browser tab and call a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that calls a function which:

- Performs an AJAX PHP request to a DB
- Displays retrieved data in a div container
- Scrolls to that bookmarked (#) div container

I'd like to have a button doing the same tasks but doing it opening a new tab and scrolling to the div. So it has to:

- Open the new tab
- Call the function that performs the request
- Display retrieved data in a div container
- Scroll to that bookmarked (#) div container

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend working with [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).
After you retrieved your Data in your AJAX callback, urlencode it and append it to the link to your route.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success : (response) => {
        window.open(
            'http://example.com/my-target-route' + '?content=' + encodeURIComponent(response.data) + '#my-div-container',
            '',
            ''
        )
    }
})
```

On your target page, parse the query parameters like that:

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let myDiv = document.querySelector('#my-div-container');

myDiv.innerHTML = urlParams.get('content');
```

Alternatively, you might try to [run a method in the new tab from local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213746/how-to-run-function-on-new-tab-from-main-tab-google-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default anchor behavior and redirect the user with 
`window.open('http://yoururl/#divContainerToScrollToID', '_blank');`

Comment: I have to open the new tab, perform the request inside it, and then scroll to the div, so it's not the correct answer, sorry.